# Prestashop : Free shipping when out of range

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6, and I have configured different shipping zones with different carriers. All of them have a 8 kg limit (higher than that they have to ask for a quote). But even though it shows the 'out of range' message later, in the cart it says 'free shipping!'. Isn't there a way, for this case, to edit this 'Free shipping' message, since the shipping won't be free anyway ?

Thank you

Comment: Look into `order-carrier.tpl` there should be a section about free shipping.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem possible to print something else in case of out-of-range behavior, even by editing the source code.